# EventMachine Rspec connection and send_data test not working

Tags: ruby, rspec, eventmachine

I'm attempting to update the `em-irc` library to make it work with current versions of Ruby, as well as update it with some new features. I'm trying to make the spec work to my changes, but it's not working as I expect.

One of the tests that's not working, regardless of the changes I introduce, is the `send_data` context.

```
  subject do
    EventMachine::IRC::Client.new
  end

  ...

  context 'send_data' do
    let(:connection) { mock('Connection') }
    before do
      subject.stub(:conn => connection)
      subject.stub(:connected => true)
    end

    it 'should return false if not connected' do
      subject.stub(:connected => false)
      subject.send_data("NICK jch").should == false
    end

    it 'should send message to irc server' do
      connection.should_receive(:send_data).with("NICK jch\r\n")
      subject.send_data("NICK jch")
    end
  end
```

Which references this function in my code:

```
  def send_data(message)
    return false unless @connected
    message = message + "\r\n"
    @conn.send_data(message)
    trigger 'send', message
  end
```

The first test works;  when `subject` is not connected, `send_data` returns false. However, the second test fails because `mock('Connection')` never receives the `send_data` calls. This is the failure I receive:

```
  1) EventMachine::IRC::Client send_data should send message to irc server
     Failure/Error: connection.should_receive(:send_data).with("NICK jch\r\n")
       (Mock "Connection").send_data("NICK jch\r\n")
           expected: 1 time with arguments: ("NICK jch\r\n")
           received: 0 times with arguments: ("NICK jch\r\n")
     # ./spec/lib/em-irc/client_spec.rb:80:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I've tried a couple changes but none of them seem to be working. I don't see why `connection` isn't receiving `send_data` calls even though I'm calling `send_data` on that mocked connection. It was working in the previous version of the library, with the only difference being I use `let(:connection){...}` rather than `@connection = mock('Connection')`.

Comment: You would need to show more of your code, including how `@connected` and perhaps `@conn` are initialized.

Comment: Would that affect things even though I'm stubbing them? I'm not very versed in `rspec`so I don't know for sure.

Comment: `@conn` and `@connected` affect how your code-under-test behaves, which affects the results you're getting. You can't stub instance variables (which is what those are), so you need to show how those instance variables are set.

Comment: Oh, really? I think the code that I changed affected that, and I was attempting to stub the instance variables. I'm guessing you have to `instance_variable_set` within the tests, then, instead of `stub`?

Answer (score 0):

in rspec, you need to have tests run inside of an event loop. I achieve that with this monkey patch:

```
RSpec::Core::Example.class_eval do
  alias ignorant_run run

  def run(example_group_instance, reporter)
    result = false

    Fiber.new do
      EM.run do
        df = EM::DefaultDeferrable.new
        df.callback do |test_result|
          result = test_result
          # stop if we are still running.
          # We won't be running if something inside the test
          # stops the run loop.
          EM.stop if EM.reactor_running?
        end
        test_result = ignorant_run example_group_instance, reporter
        df.set_deferred_status :succeeded, test_result
      end
    end.resume

    result
  end
end
```